# PHP to scan a directory and, for every file found, echo the contents of that file within it's own DIV element

Tags: javascript, php, html, foreach

This code displays a list of files in a folder on the server:

```
<div>
  <?php
    if ($handle = opendir('../trx/assets/')) {
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
          echo $entry, '<br>';
        }
      }
    closedir($handle);
   }
  ?>
</div>
```

It returns:

```
test.txt 
banana.txt 
cheese.txt
```

And this code displays the contents of one of those files in a div

```
<div>
<?php
   echo nl2br(file_get_contents( '../trx/assets/test.txt' ));
?>
</div>
```

Currently i manually look in that folder and create a div for every file then use php to echo out its contents. As the files in the "assets" folder are created by users what i would like to do is on page load have PHP automatically create divs with the contents of those files.

My thoughts were haveing a foreach loop that reads the directory and for every file found create a div and echo out its content but i dont know how to do it even after looking a the [PHP foreach documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), can anyone help?

Comment: Can you not just combine the logic of the first piece of code with the display logic in the second?

Comment: Do any of these directories have sub-folders and if so do those sub-folders contain files that need to be displayed too?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes some of them have sub directories that will need to be displayed too. But i am happy if someone can help me with the logic for just displaying the contents of the files in the top level and i will try to work out the rest from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly that you wish to scan a directory and, for every file found, echo the contents of that file within it's own `DIV` element then perhaps the following might be of help? The below was tested locally with a sub-folder of the current working directory simply called `textfiles`

```
    #'../trx/assets/'
    $dir=sprintf('%s/textfiles',__DIR__);
    
    if ( $handle = opendir($dir) ) {
      while( false !== ( $entry = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
        if( $entry != "." && $entry != ".." ) {
            
          printf(
            '<div><h1>%s</h1>%s</div>',
            $entry,
            nl2br( file_get_contents( sprintf( '%s/%s', $dir, $entry ) ) ) 
          );
        }
      }
      closedir($handle);
   }
}
```

The above will not recurse into sub-directories - simply reads from the assigned folder level. To happily recurse into sub-folders to whatever depth a `recursiveDirectoryIterator` would seem appropriate.

For recursing all sub-directories a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` in conjunction with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
if( is_object( $files ) ){
   foreach( $files as $name => $file ){
       if( !$file->isDir() && strtolower( pathinfo( $file->getFileName(),PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) )=='txt' ){
            printf(
                '<div><h1>%s</h1>%s</div>',
                $file->getFileName(),
                nl2br( file_get_contents( sprintf( '%s/%s', $dir, $file->getFileName() ) ) ) 
            );
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: That worked! thank you so much for the fast response,  saved me lots of manual effort - automation is great.

Comment: glad hat it helped - and yes, automation rocks